# How can I display a result directly on STDOUT with a shell program?

Tags: shell

The goal here it's to display directly the result on the STDOUT so on the terminal when I press CTRL+D, First I tried many things to find the solution.

So when I execute the program like `./myprog.sh`, it wait a enter, so we can write :

```
bob
cookie
```

And we we press on CRTL+D, I want this result:

```
bob
cookie
boy
dog
```

My code is:

```
while :
do
    read INPUT_STRING ||break
    case $INPUT_STRING in
    bob)
        echo "boy"
        ;;
    alicia)
        echo "girl"
        ;;
    cookie)
        echo "dog"
        ;;
    bye)
        break
        echo "      "
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown"
        ;;   
    esac

done
```

How can I display the content after write many different things in my terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the basics, what is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>? This key-combination resembles end-of-file. It is not a signal that you can catch, but it is something that is related to files. So if you want actions to happen when you press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you actually are saying that:

> I want to create a file over `/dev/stdin`, read it into memory and then perform various actions on it.

An example in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) would be:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;++i) print i,a[i]}' -
```

Here, it reads the full "file" into memory and when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you tell awk that EOF is reached and it executes the `END` statement which prints the line number and then line. They <hyphen> at the end of the script is a short-hand for `/dev/stdin`.

Now, if you want to do something like that in a shell, lets say [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to keep it simple, you can do something like this.

1. read the full input into memory by storing it into an array or a temporary file. The reading is finished when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. process the input afterwards.

This looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# declare an array, to store stuff in
declare -a myArray

# read the full file into the array
# This while loop terminates when pressing CTRL-D
i=1
while read -r line; do
   myArray[i]="${line}"
   ((i++))
done < /dev/stdin

# Process the array
for ((j=1;j<i;++j)); do
   # perform your actions here on myArray[j]
   echo "$i" "${myArray[j]}"
done
```

Comment: thank you for you explanation, but I don't really understand how can I adapt your code with mine, sorry?

Comment: @user10457278 replace `echo "$i" "${myArray[j]}"` with `case "${myArray[j]}" ... esac` this is the part where you process your "file"

Comment: @user10457278 did this help you?

Comment: Thank you for you help I understand, I was able to solve the problem